# How to create a unique id for an entire django formset?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have created a formset to submit project costs and i want each submission to have a unique id. I want to use the submission id in a url later on(ie `"projects/1/cost-submission-edit/3`"). 1 is the project's id and 3 should be the cost submission id.

The formset is defined as:

**models.py**

```
class ProjectData(models.Model):
    project_name  = models.CharField(max_digits = 20)
    client = models.CharField(max_digits= 15)

class ProjectCostSubmission(models.Model):
        project_name  = models.ForeignKey(ProjectData, max_digits = 20)
        cost_name = models.CharField(max_digits= 15)
        amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9)
        submission_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        payment_approval_date = models.DateField(auto_add_now=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.label_suffix = ""

   class Meta:
        model = ProjectData
        fields = "__all__"


MyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ProjectData,ProjectCostSubmission, form=MyForm,extra=2)
```

**views.py**

```
class ProjectCostView(CreateView):
    template_name = "/project_cost.html"
    model = ProjectCostSubmission
    fields = '__all__'
    form_class = MyForm
```

**urls.py**

```
path("/projects/<int:project_id>/cost-submission-edit/",ProjectCostView.as_view(),name="costView")
```

**After 3 submissions,the formset edit page renders the formset like this:**

```
Project Name   Client   Cost Name  Amount   Submission Date  Approval Date
------------   ------   --------   ------   ---------------  -------------
Project1       Client1  Cost A     1000.00    12/02/2019      12/03/2019      
Project1       Client1  Cost B     1000.00    12/02/2019      12/03/2019
Project1       Client1  Cost C     1000.00    12/03/2019      12/03/2019
Project1       Client1  Cost A     1000.00    12/03/2019      12/03/2019      
Project1       Client1  Cost F     1000.00    12/04/2019      12/04/2019
Project1       Client1  Cost G     1000.00    12/04/2019      12/04/2019     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total: $6000.00
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

with the url "/projects/1/cost-submission-edit/".'/1/' is the project id.
```

**Instead, i want it to look like this:**

```
url "/projects/1/cost-submission-edit/1/"


Project Name   Client   Cost Name  Amount   Submission Date  Approval Date
------------   ------   --------   ------   ---------------  -------------
Project1       Client1  Cost A     1000.00    12/02/2019      12/03/2019      
Project1       Client1  Cost B     1000.00    12/02/2019      12/03/2019
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total: $2000.00
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

url "/projects/1/cost-submission/2/"

Project Name   Client   Cost Name  Amount   Submission Date  Approval Date
------------   ------   --------   ------   ---------------  -------------
Project1       Client1  Cost C     1000.00    12/03/2019      12/03/2019
Project1       Client1  Cost A     1000.00    12/03/2019      12/03/2019
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total: $2000.00
-------------------------------------------------------------------------      

url "/projects/1/cost-submission/3/" 

Project Name   Client   Cost Name  Amount   Submission Date  Approval Date
------------   ------   --------   ------   ---------------  -------------  
Project1       Client1  Cost F     1000.00    12/04/2019      12/04/2019
Project1       Client1  Cost G     1000.00    12/04/2019      12/04/2019
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total: $2000.00
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here,each submission has a unique id and uses url path as `path("/projects/<int:project_id>/cost-submission-edit/",ProjectCostView.as_view(),name="costView")`

How can i create a unique id for each submission so that i can select and edit each submission? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is related to two elements:

**Your url should have two dynamic values.**

if you want that the url is `"/projects/1/cost-submission-edit/1/"` your url should be something like:

`path("/projects/<int:project_id>/cost-submission-edit/<int:submission_id>/",ProjectCostView.as_view(),name="costView")`

**You're not passing the dynamic values of the url to the view.** :

your view needs to receive the dynamic values of the url. Something like:

```
def viewname(request, project_id,submission_id ):
    #from here your view already knows for example what to look for in project 
    #1, subbmission 3
```

Comment: Thanks...I understand that,but how do i generate a unique submission_id every time i create a new submission?That way i can pass it to the url.Could i add it as a field in the ProjectCostSubmission model and set it as auto-incrementing?

Comment: Why don't you use the id of each record as that identifier?

Comment: Currently each record has an Id,but how will I know that records with Ids 1,2,3 or 6,7,8(for example) were created by the same submission?If each record could store the same submission _id,I can filter using that.Each time i create a submission,how can i automatically create one submission_id that is stored on each record?If I have 5 records in that submission,each should have a similar submission_id.I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Ok, then the use of an AutoField field is not going to work, since each record will increase by one just like the id does. What I would do would be to use a field  `counter_submission`in  models and in the view read the highest current value, increase it to 1, and save it with the form submission.